# Scope variable not recognized in second view with same Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I am trying to implement a login functionality that redirects a valid user to a personalized HTML view welcoming them with their name.

My first view is a login view. When the user clicks the button labeled "Log In" `ng-click` is supposed to call my controller's `$scope.login` which is supposed to validate the user, set the `$scope.needsLoggingIn` variable, and redirect to the second view (welcome page that shows the value of `$scope.needsLoggingIn`).

My problem is that the second view (which uses the same Angular Controller and Module) does not show the `$scope.needsLoggingIn` variable when I try to set it in the `$scope.login` function. It only shows the `$scope.needsLoggingIn` when I hard-coded the value like this in the controller, outside a scope function:

```
$scope.needsLoggingIn = "Betty";
```

This is the `$scope.login` function in my controller which tries to set the `$scope.needsLogging` in and is accepted in the first view but not accepted by the second view:

```
$scope.login = function (username, password) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: ('/login/' + username + '/' + password)
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        if (JSON.stringify(response.data) === '[]')
        {
            $scope.needsPasswordMessage = true;
            if ($scope.needsPasswordMessage)
                $scope.needsPasswordMessage = false;
            console.log("No match");
        } else {
            $scope.needsLoggingIn = username;
            $scope.issuccessMessage = true;
            if ($scope.isfailureMessage)
                $scope.isfailureMessage = false;
            $window.location.href = '../indextest.html';
            return response;
        }
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
    });
};
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can get my `$scope.needsLoggingIn` recognized by both HTML views, without hard-coding it into the controller? I would really like to be able to have my `$scope.login` function set the variable value and have it recognized by all views that use this particular controller.

Comment: Put it in `$rootScope` all the scopes inherit from it. Something else ... I don't think that login request with **GET** method is a good idea `url:('/login/'+ username + '/' + password  )`

Comment: Thank you!! Sorry if this is a dumb question but do all views have their own scope, even if they are using the same controller?

Comment: Read [**this**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) about the scopes at all and [**this**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope) about the $rootScope. Basically scopes are created per controller instance or directive or other places, but `$scope` is related more to controller than view

Comment: Polluting $rootScope isn't good advice. This is the kind of thing services are for.

Comment: @MikeFeltman good point and I encourage the OP to go for the service implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data that you want to have live across different views and controller instances should be handled via a service.

Basically you would create a service something like:

```
function userService($http) { 
    let service = {}
    service.needsLoggingIn = ""
    service.login = login

    return service

    function login() {
       return $http.... (your login code)
    }
}
```

Then inject the service into your control, set properties as appropriate and since the service is a singleton, those property values will be available everywhere you inject the service.